# Nice three pronged plug for WS2811 LED strips?

Tags: arduino, teensy, led-strip

I'm building a suit with under 1000 RGB LEDs on addressable WS2811 strips controlled by an Arduino---specifically I'm using at most 16m of [these WS2811 strips](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/4m-WS2811-LED-digital-strip-60leds-m-with-60pcs-WS2811-built-in-the-5050-smd-rgb/638374848.html).  Oh, the project is inspired by [Jungle Smack's amazing creation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvaMhivWsn0) and LED strip [curtain displays](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_OctoWS2811.html), though it won't be nearly so bright.

Those strips are rated at 11.5A for 4m, and my largest segment will wind up between 4.8m and 6.4m.  So I'm looking at roughly 14-18A in the two large leg arrangements.  That's white at maximum brightness though.  I'll write the software to keep the draw well below that most of the time, as I'm running on batteries.  So that range only represents brief pulses.  I'd guesstimate that 7A represents a safe bound for typical usage because even that'll kill my batteries faster than I'd like.

Any recommendations on three prong connecters for this amperage?  The control wire obviously doesn't require much amperage, but running it in the same connector simplifies getting dressed.

As an aside, I suppose FastSPI requires at least 3k for this, OctoWS2811 even more.  So I'll find an Arduino-like device with enough SRAM, maybe a Teensy++ 2.0 or Teensy 3.0.  Apparently the FastSPI has [massively improved](http://waitingforbigo.com/2013/02/19/fastspi_led2_preview_release/) support for WS2811, which had [timing issues](http://forum.pjrc.com/threads/15620-WS2811-on-Teensy-3-0-using-FastSPI_LED-library) previously.

Answer (score 2):

Since I also have worked on the same type of displays, I must say that you are in the right direction.

But the thing is, connectors highly depend on the type of wires that are connected to both led strip and connector. Your wire must have enough gauge rating wire so that it would support such huge current. [Here](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) you can find what type of wires to use for your current consumption.

Once you select the kind of wire to use, the connectors can be chosen appropriately. [This](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5-sets-3-Pin-XLR-Aviation-Plug-Audio-Cable-Panel-Power-Chassis-Metal-Connector-/221445284681) kind of connectors are simply ideal for situation. But I ended up using [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/4-Pin-Molex-IDE-to-3-Pin-CPU-Chasis-Case-Fan-Power-Connector-Cable-Adapter-/261510776579) type of connectors.

I must add that I have added the links to ebay. This does not mean that you must buy from it. I used that site just for the sake of pictures. Those kind of connectors are simply enough.